# Disjunction and the error `No product after head reduction'

Tags: coq

In CoqIde I entered the following code:

```
Theorem or_left : P -> P \/ Q.

Proof.
intros S V S_holds.
```

This produces the error  `No product even after head-reduction.` What is the problem and what does this mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that you are trying to introduce too many things with `intros`. Your goal is `P -> (P \/ Q)` (I added the parentheses for clarity). Thus, there is only one assumption to introduce, not three.

Possibly what happened is that you expect to introduce a name for `P`, a name for `Q`, and a name for the assumption that `P` holds, but in your theorem statement you are using previously defined `P` and `Q`, so there is no need to introduce names for them. In fact, if you paste your example to a fresh file you will get a different error:

> Error: The reference P was not found in the current environment.

You need something like

```
Variables P Q : Prop.
```

somewhere in your context for your code to compile.

Alternatively, you can write

```
Theorem or_left : forall (P Q : Prop), P -> P \/ Q.
```

or

```
Theorem or_left (P Q : Prop) : P -> P \/ Q.
```

The former will let you introduce `P` and `Q` with different names, while the latter has them already introduced for you.